# ¿Hay alguna forma de resetear todos los paquetes de npm?

Tags: npm

quisiera que mi `npm` este como si fuera nuevo, como al inicio antes de instalar nada, como puedo lograr esto?, estoy teniendo problemas para usar React.js solo por este motivo quiero hacer un reset de todo, por favor ayuda y gracias de antemano a la persona que se tome el tiempo de darme algunas instrucciones, saludos desde Paraguay y gracias.

Comment: Creo que la forma más sencilla es simplemente eliminar la carpeta node_modules y ejecutar nuevamente el npm install

Comment: Prueba eliminando "node_modules y package-lock.json o yarn.lock (En caso uses yarn)"  luego prueba instalando todas tus dependencias con "npm install o yarn install"

Comment: No existe una forma de hacer un reset? porque no quiero estar haciendo esto manualmente para cada proyecto.

Comment: ¿Cómo es eso de ***para cada proyecto***?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que quiere decir para cada proyecto?

Comment: ya lo solucione gracias de todos modos, encontre la respuesta aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js gracias perdon por quitarles tiempo.